# How should I select data from multiple tables for a single movie in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I don't know how to efficiently write a query that gets all data from a single movie to display in the browser in **PHP**

Currently I have a database with 7 tables:

**movies**, **actors**, **genres**, **producers**, **movie_actor**, **movie_genre**, **movie_producer**

To get all the information of 1 single movie I currently have this query:

```
SELECT 
    movies.tmdb_id, 
    movies.budget, 
    movies.title, 
    movies.description, 
    movies.runtime, 
    movies.vote_average, 
    movies.popularity, 
    movies.backdrop_path, 
    movies.poster_path, 
    movies.released_at,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT actors.name) AS movie_actor_names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT actors.poster_path) AS movie_actors_poster_path,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT movie_actor.movie_character) AS movie_actors_character,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.name) AS movie_genre_names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT producers.name) AS movie_producer_names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT producers.poster_path) AS movie_producer_poster_path
FROM 
    movies
JOIN 
    movie_actor ON movies.id = movie_actor.movie_id
JOIN
    actors ON actors.id = movie_actor.actor_id
JOIN
    movie_genre ON movies.id = movie_genre.movie_id
JOIN 
    genres ON movie_genre.genre_id = genres.id
JOIN 
    movie_producer ON movies.id = movie_producer.movie_id
JOIN
    producers ON movie_producer.producer_id = producers.id
GROUP BY
    movies.id
HAVING 
    movies.id = 9;
```

I'm stuck at this point on how to efficiently do this query since I'm gonna display the data returned in the browser with **PHP** but right now the actor is split from it's poster_path and same for the producers. What can I do better and how can I optimize this query, it feels a bit hacky right now. Should I make multiple queries? Should it be 1 query?

If you have any advise on what subjects I should learn to get into these kind of queries please tell me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you only want one movie, use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. Then it will filter the movies before all the joins rather than after, and it should be efficient.

Comment: @Barmar is the query good or should I redo this? Also I can't seem to use GROUP BY with WHERE.

Comment: I think it's OK if you make that change. Why can't you use `GROUP BY`? Did you remember that `WHERE` goes *before* `GROUP BY`?

Comment: So I replaced GROUP BY with WHERE and it returns basically the same result. I feel like this DISTINCT on each GROUP_CONCAT is a bit hacky.. Should I use subqueries? I've read something about subqueries but don't know if this is the right place to use it. Also why it feels hacky to me now is that I want the actor with the picture and now they are in seperate returns

Comment: If you were searching for multiple movies, that's what I would do -- join with subqueries that each do `GROUP_CONCAT(...) GROUP BY movie_id`. But for a single movie I think that may be overkill. But see what the performance is like.

Comment: I'm hoping that the query optimizer will do the right thing when you're selecting a single movie ID. But maybe I'm too optimistic about MySQL.

Comment: this has nothing to do which php and you need to tag ypur database system as well

Comment: @nbk with* your* - If you want to be someone that only comes in to complain instead of helping maybe this isn't the right place for you.

Comment: You can `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT actors.name, '|', actors.poster_path, '|', movie_actor.movie_character) AS movie_actors` to keep the actor data together.

Comment: @user1191247 thanks man that helped a lot! Didn't knew you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you're trying to do. I would do subqueries on the `actors`, `movie_actors`, `genre`, and `producers` tables, because you're doing the aggregations there and you could remove having to use `distinct`.

Then you could join between all the tables and use a simple `where` filter to get `movie.id = 9` instead of doing the aggregate on the entire result set.

Hope that helps